# Angular internationalization (i18n) - $localize takes default translation

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

In my Angular application, I have a table.config.ts file that exports a configuration object for a table column. The configuration includes localization using the $localize function for the column label. Here's a snippet of the configuration:

```
// table.config.ts

export let columns = {
  key: "startDate", 
  value: $localize `:@@StartDate:Start date`,
  format: "date",
};
```

when I use this configuration in my application, the translation doesn't work as expected, and it returns the default value "Start date" instead of the translated version.

This code would work an a normal component!

To troubleshoot this issue, I have ensured the following:

Localization Setup: I have properly set up Angular localization in my application, including the necessary locale files and configurations in the angular.json file.

Importing $localize: I have imported the $localize function correctly from '@angular/localize/init' at the beginning of my file.

Translation Files: I have verified that the translation key (@@StartDate) used in $localize corresponds to a valid entry in my translation files, and the translations are available in the appropriate locale file.

Locale Selection: I have confirmed that the application is running in the desired locale, and the locale preference is correctly set.

Feel free to provide additional details or code snippets if you have specific error messages or if there's more context to consider.